# sphinx - How to include a Python function as source code

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Sphinx is great at linking to specific Python objects.

For example, writing

```
:func:`foo.bar`
```

will link directly to the `bar` function in `foo.py`. I want this same functionality but, instead  of creating a clickable link, I want it to be the code of `bar()`, instead.

The `.. code-block:: language` directive requires you to manually write the code that you want to add. But I want to link to code that already exists in external Sphinx projects using [intersphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/intersphinx.html), not write the code myself. `:mod:`, `:func:`, and others only create links, not actually include source-code.

There's also `.. literalinclude:: filename` but in my case, I can't use it because the function comes from outside of the Sphinx project (It's being linked using intersphinx and isn't part of the actual project). Even if `.. literalinclude:: filename` could somehow work cross-project, I think that I'd still need to use `:lines:` to filter every function down, which would be a huge pain to keep track of.

How can refer to a function / class by its namespace path and use that to add its source-code directly into the sphinx rst file? (Not as a clickable link, but the literal code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one replied so I made my own: https://github.com/ColinKennedy/sphinx-code-include

Answer (score 2):

This feature is available out of the box. What you are looking for is the `literalinclude` directive and its `:pyobject:` argument.

```
---[mymodule.py]------------
def hello(who):
    print(f'Hello {who} !')


---[mydocumentation.rst]----

Bla bla bla lorem ipsum

.. literalinclude: ../../path/to/mymodule.py
   :pyobject: hello
```

This will only include the code of the `hello()` function in your documentation.

Comment: As mentioned in the 3rd paragraph, literalinclude wouldn't work because it requires a path, which I have no access to because it's in a different directory / git repository. Unless it can refer by namespace and still work with intersphinx, it's useless for this.