# Can sphinx.ext.viewcode allow me to include the _content_ of the source code in my doc in addition to linking to it?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm trying to avoid having to do literal includes with specific line numbers to embed snippets of my code in my docs.

I'm asking almost this same question: [sphinx - How to include a Python function as source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58277247/sphinx-how-to-include-a-python-function-as-source-code)

I want to include the *content* of the object referenced in my rst doc and have it appear as a highlighted python code snippet.

In that post no one mentions the `sphinx.ext.viewcode` plugin though, which includes the source code and generates links to it.

If `sphinx.ext.viewcode` can include the code and links in my docs is there a way to use it to include that code as a snippet in my doc pages directly as well?

For example here is what one of the links looks like:
`my_rendered_docs/_modules/module/sub_module/another_sub_module.html#my_func`

Can I include that content directly as a python code block through some relative pathing? Or does viewcode support a directive for this?

## Edit

Per comments `pyobject` is what I needed.

```
.. literalinclude :: ../../my_proj/some_path/my_module.py
   :pyobject: a_function_inside_my_module
   :linenos:
   :language: python
```

Comment: The `sphinx.ext.viewcode` is usually called an extension as the `ext` segment implies, in the context of the Sphinx application we don't usually call things "plugins".

Comment: What you want is [one of these directives](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#showing-code-examples). (These are part of Sphinx core and don't even count as extensions) I recommend the [`.. literalinclude::`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude) because it allows using relative paths from the docs directory base to selectively show lines in code - that's what you ask for in the last line of your question.

Comment: In your previous question you were asking how to cross-reference something, it has to be declared in `.rst` and by **declared** that means [one of the domain directives](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/domains/python.html) or an autodoc/autosummary declaration. If something is in the index, you can cross-reference it. However, you then have to ask yourself if you want to document your test suit or just whatever API/library you're developing. It's not common to also document tests as they're considered internals.

Comment: I explicitly said I'm asking this question because I want to avoid `literal includes with specific line numbers`. It seemed to me like viewcode is already doing the heavy lifting of grabbing the code I want to embed. I'm asking if there is a way I can grab the code its already pulling in. I also closed my previous question to create this more focused one- ie the whole question regarding my tests is no longer relevant here.

Comment: You don't have to use line numbers, you can use markers or the line itself. Yes it can break, but if you're working with files that aren't `.py` there aren't any better alternatives. Here your question becomes confusing, you mention `...another_sub_module.html#my_func` but that's an anchor in a built HTML page, it isn't source code per se. So it's not entirely clear what exactly you want. E.g what is: *"content of the object reference on the page"*? You don't give an MRE of a problem to be solved, so we're left guessing what's being aimed for.

Comment: I think it was pretty obvious (even linked to another post asking for the same thing), but I tried to make it clearer: `I want to include the _content_ of the object referenced in my rst doc and have it appear as a highlighted python code snippet.`. I want an inline code snippet grabbed directly from my python code base.

Comment: I think what you might want is using the [`:pyobject:` option](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude)?

Comment: Please add  :pyobject: as a suggested answer @bad_coder